# Entity Framework code first one to one optional

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have relation one to one with following objects:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Ecwid
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Project")]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EcwidShopID { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Project : AuditInfoComplete
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Ecwid Ecwid { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext I have:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ecwid>().HasKey(p => p.ProjectId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOptional(p => p.Ecwid).WithRequired(p => p.Project);
```

Problem: when I create Project, Entity Framework creates Ecwid object in database to, but I don't need this object. In DbContext I added "HasOptional", why EF creates Ecwid object for me?

Comment: Use [NotMapped](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I get following error: "Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property". I can not use DataMember and NotMapped on same property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HasOptional` means that EF must create new column which is ***nullable***. IF you don't want EF automatically creates a new column in database, then just map this realtionship to existing column:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Ecwid)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Project)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("Ecwid_ID"));
```

Or, if your FK column in `Ecwid` table, then change your mapping as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ecwid>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Project)
            .WithOptional(p => p.Ecwid);
```